# Failed to load __android_log_print in libtensorflowlite_jni.so

Tags: android, logging, tensorflow, android-ndk

I was trying to add some `__android_log_print` in Tensorflow Lite source code. I use the following command to generate Tensorflow Lite library (`libtensorflowlite.jar` and `libtensorflowlite_jni.so`).

```
bazel build -c opt --cxxopt='--std=c++11' //tensorflow/contrib/lite/java:tensorflowlite \
--crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
--cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

I used those two files (.jar and .so) for [TFLiteCameraDemo app](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo), which  was built via Android Studio.

However, when I opened the app on my android device (Android 7.1), it showed the following errors.

```
02-18 16:36:35.990 25543-25543/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo W/System.err: TensorFlowLite: failed to load native library: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__android_log_print" referenced by "/data/app/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo-1/lib/arm/libtensorflowlite_jni.so"...
02-18 16:36:35.992 25543-25543/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo W/System.err: TensorFlowLite: failed to load native library: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__android_log_print" referenced by "/data/app/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo-1/lib/arm/libtensorflowlite_jni.so"...
02-18 16:36:35.992 25543-25543/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/art: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.createErrorReporter(int) (tried Java_org_tensorflow_lite_NativeInterpreterWrapper_createErrorReporter and Java_org_tensorflow_lite_NativeInterpreterWrapper_createErrorReporter__I)
02-18 16:36:35.992 25543-25543/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

By the way, I have already included these lines in my `build.gradle`.

```
ndk {
        abiFilters "${cpuType}"
        ldLibs "log"
}
```

The NDK version I use is r14b.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ndk.ldLibs** relates to *deprecated* NDK plugin. These days, we use different Android Studio integration syntax.

At any rate, **bazel** silently ignores this.

You can pass `-llog` to **bazel** via [`--linkopt`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--linkopt) flag:

```
bazel build -c opt --cxxopt='--std=c++11' --linkopt='-llog' …
```

BTW, if I am not missing something, you should use `--android_cpu` instead of `--cpu`, but you can just as well skip it, because `armeabi-v7a` is the default for `--android_cpu`.